# Using Flutter Riverpod's StreamProvider to fetch a specific document from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I am using Riverpod's StreamProvider to fetch a field from Firestore containing an array then mapping it to a class as follows.

```
final firebaseFollowingProvider = StreamProvider<List<Following>>((ref) {
  final stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('following').doc('d48391af-380d-4377-a3f9-d38cf5af7923').snapshots();
  return stream.map((snapshot) => snapshot.data()!.map((doc) => Following.fromDocument(doc)).toList());
});
```

My Model looks like this

```
class Following {
  dynamic following;

  Following({this.following});

  Following.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : following = json['isFollowing'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'isFollowing': following,
      };

  factory Following.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Following(following: doc['isFollowing']);
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is

> The argument type 'MapEntry<_, *> Function(String)' can't be assigned
> to the parameter type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic> Function(String,
> dynamic)'. (Documentation) The return type 'Following' isn't a
> 'MapEntry<*, _>', as required by the closure's context.
> (Documentation)

Since `snapshot.data()` already returns a Map, how can I map the data returned from the StreamProvider to a class?

I am using `cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0`

Thank you very much.

[Structure of the Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpcc2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was I was returning a List of type Following, i.e `<List<Following>>` instead of returning `Following`

```
final firebaseFollowingProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<Following>((ref) {
  final stream = followingRef.doc('d48391af-380d-4377-a3f9-d38cf5af7923').snapshots();
  return stream.map((snapshot) => Following.fromDocument(snapshot));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't define variables as `dynamic` inside your model class. Model classes are meant to give you type safety, and `dynamic` variables escape the type system.

This would be better (haven't tested it):

```
class Following {
  final String following;

  Following({required this.following});

  Following.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : following = json['isFollowing'] as String;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'isFollowing': following,
      };

  factory Following.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Following(following: doc['isFollowing'] as String);
  }
}
```